# Joomla + Nginx = Forms won't submit

Tags: nginx, joomla

one of the problems that i'm having with is combo is that ANY form doesn't work.

For example, when i try to log in with my user, Joomla only redirects me to the same page with no message. Same trying loggin in the administrator area, the page is refreshed but it does not show my any message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when the session cookie is not set in the client. If you are using nginx for caching, you have to check if you are no hiding the Set-Cookie header. There are a lot posts who recommend it, but that can cause this problem. Anyway, Could you explain you your problem with more details.

Regards